# What is the best way to clamp your viewport to a set of predefined fixed scroll positions when resizing your window?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, resize

I'm using scroll-snapping in my web app, and it is composed of five sections which are each exactly the size of the viewport. CSS scroll snap does not behave consistently across browsers and in particular, there is no way to control the delay between the scrolling and the snapping. As a result, it feels clunky on Chrome and Edge. Therefore, I'm using a library called scroll-snap instead, but I still need to implement a handleResize function that will always keep one of the five sections centered on the screen. I've tried two separate approaches, but both are causing issues where other sections are being snapped to when resizing too quickly.

What's the best way to clamp your viewport to a fixed scroll position at all times (when resizing the window for example).
I only ever want to have five fixed scroll positions (the tops of my sections).

The first approach I tried was to have a `currentSection` variable and calculate if the `scrollTop` of the container is within the boundaries of `currentSection`'s top and bottom edges. However, when I resize the browser window, I think the scrollTop of the container is entering the bounding box of the section above and snapping to that section.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Set currentSection to the first section (introduction) if it hasn't been set yet
    if (!currentSectionRef.current) {
      currentSectionRef.current = sectionElements[0];
    }
    // Snap the scroll position to the start of the current section when resizing window
    const handleResize = (): void => {
      if (
        !scrollContainerRef.current ||
        sectionElements.length === 0 ||
        !currentSectionRef.current
      ) {
        return;
      }
      sectionElements.forEach((section) => {
        const top = section.offsetTop;
        const bottom = section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight;
        if (
          (scrollContainerRef.current as HTMLElement).scrollTop >= top &&
          (scrollContainerRef.current as HTMLElement).scrollTop < bottom
        ) {
          currentSectionRef.current = section;
        }
      });
      scrollContainerRef.current.scrollTo(
        0,
        currentSectionRef.current.offsetTop
      );
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, [sectionElements]);
```

I also tried doing the following where I'd calculate which section is the nearest and snap to it, and this behaved slightly better. It wouldn't automatically snap to the wrong sections every time, but would snap to wrong sections whenever resizing too quickly.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Snap the scroll position to the start of the nearest section when resizing window
    const handleResize = (): void => {
      if (!scrollContainerRef.current || sectionElements.length === 0) {
        return;
      }
      const scrollPosition = scrollContainerRef.current.scrollTop;

      const distancesToSections = sectionElements.map((element) =>
        Math.abs(scrollPosition - element.offsetTop)
      );
      let shortestDistanceToSection = Math.min(...distancesToSections);
      let nearestSectionIndex = distancesToSections.indexOf(
        shortestDistanceToSection
      );
      let nearestSection = sectionElements[nearestSectionIndex];

      nearestSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "auto" });
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, [sectionElements]);
```

How can I change my code to always snap to the top of my current section when resizing the browser so that the viewport never gets stuck at any point in between two sections? Essentially, I only want five scrollable positions, and the scroll-snap library ensures this when scrolling, but resizing breaks this design. I'd appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: What did your implementation with scroll snap look like and what was the clunky behavior? I haven't experienced that before

Comment: @Wayne Just standard scroll-snap-type: y mandatory on container and scroll-snap-align: start on children. The clunky behavior is basically a delay after your scroll before the snapping actually happens. I want to implement functionality as seen here: https://olaolu.dev/ but instead I got functionality as seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-snap-react-hooks-pppv8w except even worse with CSS scroll-snap

Comment: I see the example you gave is very smooth maybe they added a transition effect? Sorry, I can't be more help, but this is out of my league on the topic. I am interested in what the solution ends up being tho.